# mysql locking question

Tags: php, mysql, table-lock

Investigating/researching mysql/myisam locking. trying to find a good example of how to set the lock in appA, and determine/detect the tbl lock in appB.

searching google, not seeing much, so i must be missing something.

i'm going to be writing a php app that demonstrates this process.

pointers/thoughts/thanks..

-tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at MySQLs GET_LOCK() function.

Follow this link to get more information: [MySQL Documentation for GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)

This looks like it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's GET_LOCK function gets named user locks, which are an extra feature MySQL provides over and above anything to do with tables.

No tables are involved so it does not invoke the storage engine and has nothing to do with myisam. GET_LOCK is available on all supported mysql versions regardless of what engines are used.